# Open two instances of Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to have two Notepad++ shortcuts in desktop, imagine to have two Notepad++ installed each with their exe icon shortcut, that is what I want, so I will can work in two projects,

I have tried all with instances, and "multiins" or "atl + f6", but it does not work as I want,

again, this is different to another questions with the same title, I want to have two shortcut icons of notepad++, each one opening their files opened,

if it is not possible, I will need to use notepad++ and sublime-text at the same time, but that will be a very ugly option

Thanks, I am using notepad++ 5.9.6

(imagine to open notepad++ and sublimetext, working different project in each one, I want to do that but only with notepad++ opening two notepads++,  :P)

Comment: Did you tried open two instances of the portable version?

Comment: do you know if I can use plugins with portable version?

Comment: Yes, notepad++ installer have an option to not place plugins at %AppData%

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you open the second file, whilst it opens as a second tab you can just grab the tab and drag it out of Notepad++ to open it in a second session. Sort of like how Firefox, Chrome and IE do it with tabs.

Comment: yes, but when I close, it is just as a single instance, opening notepad++ again, only will appear one of the windows,

Comment: as GYBE wrote in his solution, Setings -> Preferences -> Multi-Instance -> Always in multi-instance mode, in my case this does the job really

Comment: Dragging a tab out of the window does not open it with a new window.... I have enabled multi-instance mode. I can open a new window by double-clicking the application's icon, but how to move a document to another window? PS: Dragging out worked with a file.... but not with a new document in memory.

Comment: I like this solution because I don't want to lose the behavior of a single instance. It is only on special scenarios that I need two instances. It is also good to notice that this doesn't work if it is a new document not saved yet.

Comment: Dragging it out works for me when I am using saved files.  It opens a the tab in a new window.  One weird thing is that if  I have a new (unsaved) tab that I'm just using for "scratch paper/scribble notes", it does not work.  I guess I just need to have a garbage text file saved somewhere so that I can use it for scratch.

Answer (score 48):

From the [documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Multiple_Instances):

> You can launch Notepad++ with the `-multiInst` Command Line Switches.
>   This will enable launching extra instances when opening files by
>   double click or right click. Any command line will do, including the
>   one that you can access from the Properties of the desktop shortcut.
>
> You can always send a document being edited to another instance from
>   the View menu or the tab right click menu, or call *Run -> Open in
>   another instance*, regardless of this setting.
>
> To force one file per instance Notepad-like behaviour, see
>   Notepad-like Behaviour. This will hide the tab bar, but you can
>   restore it from *Settings -> Preferences -> Tab bar*.
>
> You can also access the properties of the Explorer Context Menu, and
>   plug the `-multiInst` switch in the command line available there.
>
> The *Settings -> Preferences -> Multi-Instance* preference widget allows
>   choosing between the way Notepad++ handles multiple instances:
>
> - by default, us single instance mode
> - always use multiple instances
> - open session in new instance

Comment: Two additional notes: This feature works only with unmodified files on disk (and not with new files that have not been saved yet and not with files on disk that have unsaved changes in the editor).

Comment: -multiInst works. Open a stupid same tabs instance but works. thx.

Answer (score 17):

There is a shortcut to open in new instance Alt + F6.
Also if you want to open always in new instance than go to settings->prefrences->Multi-instance , here you can select option to always in multi-instance mode.

Comment: Welcome to SO. But is already answerd in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331653/1574221

Comment: @marsh-wiggle: [This one]((https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234002/372239) is better!

Comment: Not sure why anyone's discouraging this simple and eloquent answer - it's ultimately what I resorted to as it was the simplest to trudge through and solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found how to do it:

1. Settings > Preferences > Multi-Instance > Always in multi-instance mode
2. If new a file, multi-instance is not working. Need to save this file first and then move the tab out of window.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ runs on a single instance even while running on different windows.You can find another example of such application in Microsoft Office's Excel. You open files windows, but it runs exactly on one process (EXCEL.EXE).

Answer (score 0):

I just drag and drop a tab from existing session onto the desktop and it opens another instance.

Comment: Next time, make sure to read more than just the title of the question.

Comment: @NathanTuggy In fairness, this answer seems to be identical (as far as I can tell) to the accepted answer. Which I also thought didn't answer the question, but...

Answer (score 0):

The github repo of notepadd++

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus

shows what happens. it sets a bool based on the multi instance setting:

```
const NppGUI & nppGUI = nppParameters.getNppGUI();
if (nppGUI._multiInstSetting == multiInst)
{
    isMultiInst = true;
    // Only the first launch remembers the session
    if (!TheFirstOne)
        cmdLineParams._isNoSession = true;
}
```

If not multi instance the code searches for another instance and copies the new data into that one:

```
    if ((!isMultiInst) && (!TheFirstOne))
    {
        HWND hNotepad_plus = ::FindWindow(Notepad_plus_Window::getClassName(), NULL);
....
        COPYDATASTRUCT paramData;
        paramData.dwData = COPYDATA_PARAMS;
        paramData.lpData = &dto;
        paramData.cbData = sizeof(dto);
        ::SendMessage(hNotepad_plus, WM_COPYDATA, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(hInstance), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&paramData));
```

So yeah, just set multi-instance in settings